# How to display the query result without reloading the page?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery, codeigniter-2

I want to show my users data from my mysql database without reloading the page.

I am using Codeigniter. I have a dropdown menu like the following, - when the page loads I want it to show all data by default. But when any user selects any name it will query to database and show results immediately without having the page reloaded.

I already have a controller, model and view to display all data from database but I don't know how to get the dropdown menu work after a person has selected a value, to fetch data from database and show immediately without reloading the page.

I have some basic knowledge of PHP but I have no idea about AJAX. Would you please kindly give me an example or idea on how to do this?

I am not expecting you to write the code for me, I am just asking for an example or a guideline. :)

Thanks in Advance.

```
  <form>
  <select name="info">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="11080101">John</option>
  <option value="11080102">Bon Jovi</option>
 </select>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like with what you are aiming to achieve this isn't really a codeigniter related question but more a HTML, JQUERY question.

[Using jQuery To Manipulate and Filter Data](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-jquery-to-manipulate-and-filter-data/) over at Net-tuts shows a jquery solution to sorting and filtering data. Their solution is based on a table but the principals are there so a modification can get it to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

well i can give you the flow of how can you try it

1. trigger a jquery event on selecting an dropdown menu item. if you don't have any idea how to do it try reading [the documentation of jquery for using selectors](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) .
2. once you have the selected element , extract its value and send an ajax call to your path
   like this (for jquery ajax visit [jqapi](http://jqapi.com) it has all the documentation for jquery ajax functions and its derivatives)

   ```
   $.post('/user/data/' + id , function(response) {
       console.log(response)
   })
   ```

   or

   ```
   $.post('/user/data/', 'id=' + id , function(response) {
       console.log(response)
   })
   ```
3. and now you have your data in reponse so you can do whatever you wish to do with it

Comment: The poster wants to fetch data, not change anything in the database. In other words, a GET request would be more appropriate.

Furthermore, in your second example you're constructing the query string by hand. This is not necessary. A better way to do it is like this:

`$.post('/user/data', {id: theId}, function(response) {console.log(response)});`